# jQuery focus() difference in Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

Having a weird problem. Ubuntu Chrome vs FireFox. On Firefox, it works fine, on Chrome it puts me in an endless loop of alerts. Why?

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#craigslist-send-email-text-box-123').focusIn(function(){
        alert('why does this alert repeat in Chrome but not in FF?');
        jQuery('#email-message-123').slideDown();
    });
});
```

In Chrome it seems to continuously loop over the focus, forcing me to click the "prevent dialogues" or I can't escape the alert loop. On my tablet Chrome, it seems to work. Ubuntu issue?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Itis a bug. When you focus, it calls the alert (loosing focus), then when it completes, focus is returned, calling the loop. Chrome handles it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to cover for chrome:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($e){

    jQuery('#craigslist-send-email-text-box-123').focusIn(function(){
       alert('why does this alert repeat in Chrome but not in FF?');
       jQuery('#email-message-123').slideDown();
       $e.preventDefault(); //weird but see if that gets around the bug.
    });
});
```